# How to Extract the Infopath form attachments to a folder?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

I am Trying to Extract the Infopath form attachments to other sharepoint library , Can someone help me to extract using some or the other way.
I am using SharePoint 2013 with Infopath form 2010 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Extensive search found dead easy way to extract the attachments from infopath forms.

1. Open the SharePoint Site in SharePoint Designer
2. Go to All Files
3. Go to Lists
4. Go to List where your infopathform is deployed to create a new item
5. Go to Attachments folder

And there you go you find each and every folder with all the attachments of infopathform available for you to access.

Comment: This is exactly the same as the above, previously given answer, and doesn't really provide any other value besides mentioning that SPD was used.

Comment: He did mentioned to cppy the location but i tried to access it directly there is no way to access it and if you want to go to that location you need to add a network location nor through spd and he also mentioned using work flow and what i told was OOB

Comment: Is there anyway to locate and browse through the Attachments folder without SharePoint Designer?

Answer (score 0):

Documents attached in the InfoPath Form are actually saved in a hidden folder. 
For example: If your list/library is TestList the attachments will be stored in [sitename]/TestList/Attachments/[filename]
If you right click on the attachment and select 'Copy Shortcut' you will get the path. Use that path in your workflow to copy the attachment to other library.

Comment: I am kind of very new to this environment can you elaborate it more clearly

Comment: Sure, to copy files from one library to other, you will need to run a workflow. You can either use SharePoint Designer or Nintax to create that workflow. In that workflow you will have to define a path from source to destination. The above explanation will help you get the attachment path. Let me know if you have question regarding SharePoint workflow

Answer (score -1):

SOLVED: Please refer to the link below

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2019/03/sharepoint-online-copy-attachments-from-list-to-document-library.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/118184)